# Three.js Spotlight casting shadow without an object

Tags: three.js

I am facing a problem where a `THREE.SpotLight` is casting a Shadow without an object beeing in its frustum.

I have setup a simple scene containing a `THREE.SpotLight` and a plane-mesh. The SpotLight is set to cast Shadows and the plane to receive Shadows. There is a square Shadow visible on the ground plane, which is the size of the SpotLights `shadowCamera`. This scene is the right hand side of the image below.

A cube-mesh is now added and positioned **outside** the initial camera viewspace. By zooming out, a bit before the cube-mesh becomes visible to the camera, the Spotlight Shadow disappears. This is pictured in the left hand side of the image.

http://jsfiddle.net/L0rdzbej/157/

This happens in Firefox, from what I heared it is not the case in Chrome. What is happening here and how to avoid it?

[image]

Comment: Does the problem go away if you call `box.updateMatrixWorld()` after you set the box's position?

Comment: No: http://jsfiddle.net/L0rdzbej/158/. The box is not the problem, when adding any object (SpotLight-Helper for example) the Shadow is gone too.

Comment: My conjecture is you are seeing the shadow of the box. Can you change the box to a sphere and try it?

Comment: The Shadow is independent from the box, it is always there even when no other mesh is in the scene (except the ground plane). The box is just there as an example mesh, it isnt even set to cast a Shadow. However, this is the same scene with a ```SphereGeometry```: http://jsfiddle.net/L0rdzbej/159/

Comment: Can you try the dev branch?

Comment: Same behavior for me, ```three.js``` ```r74dev``` hotlinked from github: http://jsfiddle.net/L0rdzbej/160/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97211/discussion-between-westlangley-and-falk-thiele).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The shadow does not show up anymore, so im marking this as solved.

Edit: In case anyone comes a long who is facing the same problem, here is a link to the reported issue on github: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/7750. It hasnt got much attention because it couldnt be reproduced by the maintainers.

Comment: Do you know what you did to fix it? It might help others in future with a similar problem.

Comment: I did not change anything with intent. Just checked the jsfiddle today with Chrome/IE/FF and its not showing up anymore.